# Questions regarding Solving Melitz (2003) model

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, international-trade, international-economics, theory

I am editing my question regarding solving the model in order to be more specific.

**Regarding the demand side**, In the beginning of the model, we have a CES utility function over a continuum of goods [image]

and we have this aggregate price: [image]

How do we use them to get these two equations ? (this is my first question)
[image]

**Regarding the production side**, there is only one factor of production which is labor and it is in-elastically supplied, the cost function represents constant marginal costs and overhead cost. l = f +q/$\phi$.I understand that in order to get this pricing rule :

[image]

we should get the first order condition of the profit function, however I do not know where does the 1/$\rho$ came from ? (this is my second question)

I apologize if these questions seem silly but I do not have a theoretical background and I am trying to solve the model by myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "solving" the model? Are you trying to derive all the results from the basic equations?

Comment: If you are not a theory person, may I ask why you are doing this for your thesis...?

Comment: I need it as a theoretical motivation, the main contribution of my thesis is not theoretical, it is empirical, but I need a theoretical framework to motivate it and therefore I want to understand the model.

Comment: Do you have a particular advice on this ? when I started my PhD I did not intend to do this, but I was told that it would be asked from me during my first thesis committee. That is why I am asking.

Comment: I am not familiar with the model, but you might get better responses if you edit your question to clarify/narrow down what it is exactly that you are looking for.

Comment: I suggest you post the specific parts you are struggling with.

Comment: Thank you both ! I will have another look to the model and ask more specific questions.

Comment: Hello, I modified my question as you suggested ? Would you have an advise on this ?